# How to add a diagonal ribbon to an imageview within Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

According to the designs, our image views are supposed to add a label on top of the view. This label should contain text, such as '50%' to indicate that the item within the image has been discounted by 50%.

How would one draw such a label / ribbon on top of an existing image view within Jetpack Compose?

EDIT: The image used is an image from an URL, which is currently being loaded using 'AsyncImage' from Coil, if this matters

Thanks in advance!
[image: Example of the image view]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Solving this requires simple math, Drawscope with rotation, TextMeasurer to measure text width and height. And composed Modifier if you wish to have these as Modifier. Built one with solid background another with shimmer effect to. You can check if painter.state is success before applying these modifiers.

Result

[image]

Modifier Implementations

```
fun Modifier.drawDiagonalLabel(
    text: String,
    color: Color,
    style: TextStyle = TextStyle(
        fontSize = 18.sp,
        fontWeight = FontWeight.SemiBold,
        color = Color.White
    ),
    labelTextRatio: Float = 7f
) = composed(
    factory = {

        val textMeasurer = rememberTextMeasurer()
        val textLayoutResult: TextLayoutResult = remember {
            textMeasurer.measure(text = AnnotatedString(text), style = style)
        }


        Modifier
            .clipToBounds()
            .drawWithContent {
                val canvasWidth = size.width
                val canvasHeight = size.height

                val textSize = textLayoutResult.size
                val textWidth = textSize.width
                val textHeight = textSize.height

                val rectWidth = textWidth * labelTextRatio
                val rectHeight = textHeight * 1.1f

                val rect = Rect(
                    offset = Offset(canvasWidth - rectWidth, 0f),
                    size = Size(rectWidth, rectHeight)
                )

                val sqrt = sqrt(rectWidth / 2f)
                val translatePos = sqrt * sqrt

                drawContent()
                withTransform(
                    {
                        rotate(
                            degrees = 45f,
                            pivot = Offset(
                                canvasWidth - rectWidth / 2,
                                translatePos
                            )
                        )
                    }
                ) {
                    drawRect(
                        color = color,
                        topLeft = rect.topLeft,
                        size = rect.size
                    )
                    drawText(
                        textMeasurer = textMeasurer,
                        text = text,
                        style = style,
                        topLeft = Offset(
                            rect.left + (rectWidth - textWidth) / 2f,
                            rect.top + (rect.bottom - textHeight) / 2f
                        )
                    )
                }

            }
    }
)


fun Modifier.drawDiagonalShimmerLabel(
    text: String,
    color: Color,
    style: TextStyle = TextStyle(
        fontSize = 18.sp,
        fontWeight = FontWeight.SemiBold,
        color = Color.White
    ),
    labelTextRatio: Float = 7f,
) = composed(
    factory = {

        val textMeasurer = rememberTextMeasurer()
        val textLayoutResult: TextLayoutResult = remember {
            textMeasurer.measure(text = AnnotatedString(text), style = style)
        }

        val transition = rememberInfiniteTransition()

        val progress by transition.animateFloat(
            initialValue = 0f,
            targetValue = 1f,
            animationSpec = infiniteRepeatable(
                animation = tween(3000, easing = LinearEasing),
                repeatMode = RepeatMode.Reverse
            )
        )

        Modifier
            .clipToBounds()
            .drawWithContent {
                val canvasWidth = size.width
                val canvasHeight = size.height

                val textSize = textLayoutResult.size
                val textWidth = textSize.width
                val textHeight = textSize.height

                val rectWidth = textWidth * labelTextRatio
                val rectHeight = textHeight * 1.1f

                val rect = Rect(
                    offset = Offset(canvasWidth - rectWidth, 0f),
                    size = Size(rectWidth, rectHeight)
                )

                val sqrt = sqrt(rectWidth / 2f)
                val translatePos = sqrt * sqrt

                val brush = Brush.linearGradient(
                    colors = listOf(
                        color,
                        style.color,
                        color,
                    ),
                    start = Offset(progress * canvasWidth, progress * canvasHeight),
                    end = Offset(
                        x = progress * canvasWidth + rectHeight,
                        y = progress * canvasHeight + rectHeight
                    ),
                )

                drawContent()
                withTransform(
                    {
                        rotate(
                            degrees = 45f,
                            pivot = Offset(
                                canvasWidth - rectWidth / 2,
                                translatePos
                            )
                        )
                    }
                ) {
                    drawRect(
                        brush = brush,
                        topLeft = rect.topLeft,
                        size = rect.size
                    )
                    drawText(
                        textMeasurer = textMeasurer,
                        text = text,
                        style = style,
                        topLeft = Offset(
                            rect.left + (rectWidth - textWidth) / 2f,
                            rect.top + (rect.bottom - textHeight) / 2f
                        )
                    )
                }

            }
    }
)
```

Usage

```
Column(
    modifier = Modifier
        .background(backgroundColor)
        .fillMaxSize()
        .padding(20.dp)
) {
    val painter1 = rememberAsyncImagePainter(
        model = ImageRequest.Builder(LocalContext.current)
            .data("https://www.techtoyreviews.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/5152094_Cover_PS5.jpg")
            .size(coil.size.Size.ORIGINAL) // Set the target size to load the image at.
            .build()
    )

    Image(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .aspectRatio(4 / 3f)
            .then(
                if (painter1.state is AsyncImagePainter.State.Success) {
                    Modifier.drawDiagonalLabel(
                        text = "50%",
                        color = Color.Red
                    )
                } else Modifier
            ),
        painter = painter1,
        contentScale = ContentScale.FillBounds,
        contentDescription = null
    )

    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))

    val painter2 = rememberAsyncImagePainter(
        model = ImageRequest.Builder(LocalContext.current)
            .data("https://i02.appmifile.com/images/2019/06/03/03ab1861-42fe-4137-b7df-2840d9d3a7f5.png")
            .size(coil.size.Size.ORIGINAL) // Set the target size to load the image at.
            .build()
    )

    Image(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .aspectRatio(4 / 3f)
            .then(
                if (painter2.state is AsyncImagePainter.State.Success) {
                    Modifier.drawDiagonalShimmerLabel(
                        text = "40% OFF",
                        color = Color(0xff4CAF50),
                        labelTextRatio = 5f
                    )
                } else Modifier
            ),
        painter = painter2,
        contentScale = ContentScale.FillBounds,
        contentDescription = null
    )
}
```

### Without any states draw to Image

[image]

```
@Composable
private fun RibbonSample() {

    val text = "50%"
    val textMeasurer = rememberTextMeasurer()
    val style = TextStyle(
        fontSize = 18.sp,
        fontWeight = FontWeight.SemiBold,
        color = Color.White
    )
    val textLayoutResult: TextLayoutResult = remember {
        textMeasurer.measure(text = AnnotatedString(text), style = style)
    }

    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .clipToBounds()
            .drawWithContent {

                val canvasWidth = size.width

                val textSize = textLayoutResult.size
                val textWidth = textSize.width
                val textHeight = textSize.height

                val rectWidth = textWidth * 7f
                val rectHeight = textHeight * 1.1f

                val rect = Rect(
                    offset = Offset(canvasWidth - rectWidth, 0f),
                    size = Size(rectWidth, rectHeight)
                )

                val translatePos = sqrt(rectWidth / 2f) * sqrt(rectWidth / 2f)

                drawContent()
                withTransform(
                    {
                        rotate(
                            degrees = 45f,
                            pivot = Offset(
                                canvasWidth - rectWidth / 2,
                                translatePos
                            )
                        )
                    }
                ) {
                    drawRect(
                        Color.Red,
                        topLeft = rect.topLeft,
                        size = rect.size
                    )
                    drawText(
                        textMeasurer = textMeasurer,
                        text = text,
                        style = style,
                        topLeft = Offset(
                            rect.left + (rectWidth - textWidth) / 2f,
                            rect.top + (rect.bottom - textHeight) / 2f
                        )
                    )
                }

            }
    ) {
        Image(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .aspectRatio(4 / 3f),
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.landscape1),
            contentScale = ContentScale.FillBounds,
            contentDescription = null
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: I get this error: Jetpack Compose 1.5.0-alpha01
                                                                                                    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: maxHeight(-4) must be >= than minHeight(0)

Comment: @EmmanuelMtali did you found any solution for the above issue ?

Comment: @HanifShaikh yes, i dont remember. I think it was something to do with setting height to zero. I have posted an answer with my solution

Answer (score 0):

You can use it as Modifier extension

```
fun Modifier.drawDiagonalLabel(
    text: String,
    color: Color,
    labelTextRatio: Float = 3f,
    style: TextStyle? = null
) = this.composed(
    factory = {

        val textMeasurer = rememberTextMeasurer()
        val currentStyle: TextStyle = style ?: TextStyle(
            fontSize = 18.sp,
            fontWeight = FontWeight.SemiBold,
            color = Color.White
        )

        val textLayoutResult: TextLayoutResult = remember {
            textMeasurer.measure(text = AnnotatedString(text), style = currentStyle)
        }


        Modifier
            .clipToBounds()
            .drawWithContent {
                val canvasWidth = size.width

                val textSize = textLayoutResult.size
                val textWidth = textSize.width
                val textHeight = textSize.height

                val rectWidth = textWidth * labelTextRatio
                val rectHeight = textHeight * 1.1f

                val rect = Rect(
                    offset = Offset(canvasWidth - rectWidth, 0f),
                    size = Size(rectWidth, rectHeight)
                )

                val sqrt = sqrt(rectWidth / 2f)
                val translatePos = sqrt * sqrt

                drawContent()
                withTransform(
                    {
                        rotate(
                            degrees = 45f,
                            pivot = Offset(
                                canvasWidth - rectWidth / 2,
                                translatePos
                            )
                        )
                    }
                ) {
                    drawRect(
                        color = color,
                        topLeft = rect.topLeft,
                        size = rect.size
                    )
                    drawText(
                        textMeasurer = textMeasurer,
                        text = text,
                        style = currentStyle,
                        topLeft = Offset(
                            rect.left + (rectWidth - textWidth) / 2f,
                            rect.top + (rect.bottom - textHeight) / 2f
                        )
                    )
                }

            }
    }
)
```

Usage (Maybe there is a better approach)

```
Surface(
    modifier = modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .let {
            if (isDebug()) {
                it.drawDiagonalLabel(
                    text = statingText,
                    color = Color.Red.copy(alpha = 0.5f)
                )
            } else {
                it
            }
        },
    color = MaterialTheme.colors.background
)
```