# Jetpack Compose debug banner like that on flutter

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am stuck trying to recreate a flutter-like debug banner with jetpack compose

[image]

Can someone help?

Comment: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/11286032)

Comment: If what ask is diagonal banner you can check out this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/74751972/5457853