# Banner design in android kotlin and jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I want to design a banner like [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hniyh.png) in jetpack compose. Specially the red "50% off" section. In CSS this should be done by positioning(relative and absolute) with rotation. But as I'm new in android I don't have any clue how to make this perfect.

I have tried like this way but design is broken:

```
@Composable
fun AnnualPlan() {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
//                .padding(16.dp)
            .background(Color.White)
    ) {
        Column(
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
        ) {
            Text(text = "Annual Plan", fontSize = 30.sp)
            Text(text = "Equal to $5/month", fontSize = 20.sp)
            Text(
                text = "$59.99 billed annually",
                fontSize = 20.sp,
                color = Color.Gray
            )
            Text(
                text = "50% off",
                fontSize = 14.sp,
                color = Color.Black,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .background(Color.Red)
                    .padding(5.dp)
                    .align(Alignment.End)
                    .rotate(-60f)
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please check this issuse https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74742032/how-to-add-a-diagonal-ribbon-to-an-imageview-within-jetpack-compose